# gulp-git: Using push results in a stream error

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, gulp

I'm trying to push to my remote repository using the [gulp-git](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-git) module from npm. The add & commit portion runs fine, but it runs into a stream error when trying to perform the remote push.

```
bump: function () {
  var branch = argv.branch || 'development';
  fs.readFile('./package.json', function (err, data) {
    if (err) { return ; }
    return gulp.src(['./package.json', './bower.json'])
      .pipe(git.add())
      .pipe(git.commit('chore(core): bump to ' + JSON.parse(data).version))
      .pipe(git.push('origin', branch, function(err) {
        if(err) throw (err);
      }));
  });
}
```

The stack trace:

> C:\src\git\ig\node_modules\gulp-git\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:623
>
> var written = dest.write(chunk);
>
> ```
>                 ^
> ```
>
> TypeError: undefined is not a function
>       at write (C:\src\git\ig\node_modules\gulp-git\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:623:24)
>       at flow (C:\src\git\ig\node_modules\gulp-git\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:632:7)
>       at DestroyableTransform.pipeOnReadable (C:\src\git\ig\node_modules\gulp-git\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:664:5)
>       at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:104:17)
>       at emitReadable_ (C:\src\git\ig\node_modules\gulp-git\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:448:10)
>       at emitReadable (C:\src\git\ig\node_modules\gulp-git\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:444:5)
>       at readableAddChunk (C:\src\git\ig\node_modules\gulp-git\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:187:9)
>       at DestroyableTransform.Readable.push (C:\src\git\ig\node_modules\gulp-git\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:149:10)
>       at DestroyableTransform.Transform.push (C:\src\git\ig\node_modules\gulp-git\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_transform.js:145:32)
>       at Array.forEach (native)

I'm running gulp-git version 1.6.0. It looks like they are at 1.7.0. Maybe the upgrade path would help however this seems like a pretty standard usage of the command, so I think it's something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the branch name is correct?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst - turns out that the issue was trying to do git.push while it was in a stream. See answer below if you're curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With help from [stevelacy](https://github.com/stevelacy) (the project admin) I was able to make it work with this code change:

```
.pipe(git.commit('chore(core): bump to ' + JSON.parse(data).version))
.on('end', function() {
  git.push('origin', branch, function(err) {
    if(err) throw (err);
  });

});
```

It turns out that the git push command cannot be done from a stream as of yet.

Comment: That does indeed make sense!

Comment: strange, that this information didn't described in official documentary, and almost nowhere.